# Strange lag which disappears by clicking anywhere on the html body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some overlay elements which are `display: none` initially but turn to `display: inline` when I hover over specific items on the page, and disappear again when the mouse hovers over something else. Exactly same behavior as tool-tips with the difference that this overlay objects have clickable and interactive elements (such as a [jquery accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)).

Everything works perfectly, until I interact with these overlay elements, i.e. click on one of the clickable items in the overlay element. Then, **once that overlay item becomes `display:none` again**, the page becomes extremely laggy in terms of how long it takes when I hover over an item to find its corresponding overlay element (they are selected by their id) and for it to appear and disappear.

**The strange thing is that if I click anywhere on the html body, the lag disappears and everything becomes fast as in the beginning.**

Out of despair, I have tried to programmatically call `blur`, `focus`, `trigger('click')` once the overlay element is set back to `display:none` but none has helped so far, and I have to manually click on the page for the lag to go away.

Any idea what causes such behavior and how I can fix it? thanks,

**Edit**: code

CSS part:

```
span.overlay {
    z-index:10;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}    
span.visible { display:inline; }
```

HTML part: lots of such `span` elements, each with their own unique id.

```
<span class='overlay ui-widget-content' id='xyz'>
   <!-- lots of stuff here -->
</span>
```

javascript part:

```
/* displays overlay element when user hovers over the first td */
$('table.foo > tbody > tr > td:first-child').hover(
    function(e) {
        $(this).parent().tooltip('disable');
        var elem = $('#' + $(this).parent().data('overlay-id'));
        if (!elem.hasClass('visible')) {
            elem.css('left', e.pageX + 20).css('top', e.pageY).addClass('visible');
            elem.find('.accordion:first').accordion('refresh');
        }
    }, function() {
        var elem = $('#' + $(this).parent().data('overlay-id'));
        if (! elem.is(':hover') && ! elem.hasClass('pin')) {
            $(elem).removeClass('visible');
        }
        $(this).parent().tooltip('enable');
    });

/* if mouse leaves span.visible and it is not pinned it will hide the span */
$('body').on('mouseleave', 'span.visible',
    function() {
      if (!$(this).hasClass('pin')) {
        $(this).removeClass('visible');
      }
    });
```

**Edit**: profiling the code, it seems that `get offsetHeight` and `get offsetWidth` take way longer than before. Yet I do not know why this should happen and why it should go away by clicking on the page.

[image: profile]
[image: profile-2]

previously, when I do not observe the problem, these two functions each take less than 3%.

Comment: Without code its difficult to say...

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo showing the problem? Which browsers have you tested?

Comment: @thirtydot I will try to reproduce this problem in jsfiddle, but given than this is a lag issue, my guess is that it goes away for a small jsfiddle example. The actual page is very huge and I think that exacerbates whatever is causing the lag in the first place.

Comment: @thirtydot as for the browser, I only have access to chrome (due to system administrative issues)

Comment: Try replacing that `.hover()` with delegated events for `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`. If that doesn't help, I'm going to need a test case.

Comment: @thirtydot isn't `hover` just a short-cut for those two? any idea why should the lag disappear if i click anywhere on the html page?

Comment: Well, it's the "delegated" part of my comment that's important. Read http://api.jquery.com/on/ carefully. Though after looking at your profile, I don't think this is relevant to your problem. I have no idea why the lag disappears when you click. I'll take a look if you can get a test case up.

Comment: Hi, could you unfold "get offsetHeight" profile to see what happened underneath?

Comment: @EmmanuelTabard now i see the lag on `get offsetY`. I added a new pic for that

Answer (score 0):

try binding the `mouseleave` event upon opening the "tooltip". Replace your code with this (not tested):

```
/* displays overlay element when user hovers over the first td */
$('table.foo > tbody > tr > td:first-child').on('mouseenter',
    function(e) {
        $(this).parent().tooltip('disable');
        var elem = $('#' + $(this).parent().data('overlay-id'));
        if (!elem.hasClass('visible')) {
            elem.css('left', e.pageX + 20).css('top', e.pageY).addClass('visible');
            elem.find('.accordion:first').accordion('refresh');

            // notice the "ONE" handler, it'll unbind the event after execution
            elem.one('mouseleave', function() {
                if (!$(this).hasClass('pin')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('visible');
                }
                $(this).parent().tooltip('enable');
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Notice the `one` listener to unbind the event after it's first execution.
I can't guarantee that this will fix your issue but I experienced lots of performance hits when a page has A LOT of elements and browsers need to check hover events that change very quickly.
This way the browser only needs to check one mouseleave event. And if it happened, it's gone again. It seems you may have too many bound events and don't clean them up properly.

I'm not sure if I replicated your desired functionality correctly so please add code if I missed something. I was unsure why exactly you'd need to bind a mouseleave event via `body` AND via `.hover()`.